# If i click the contact us button, the modal won't open

Tags: javascript, html, css, bootstrap-5

I am trying to program a modal in bootstrap 5.2 but the "Contact Us" button won't open the Modal.

What am I missing?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="html" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/html">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <title>UNIFINITY Worldwide</title>
  <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-rbsA2VBKQhggwzxH7pPCaAqO46MgnOM80zW1RWuH61DGLwZJEdK2Kadq2F9CUG65" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/6.4.2/css/all.min.css" integrity="sha512-z3gLpd7yknf1YoNbCzqRKc4qyor8gaKU1qmn+CShxbuBusANI9QpRohGBreCFkKxLhei6S9CQXFEbbKuqLg0DA==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"/>
</head>
<body>
  <div class="container border">

    <!-- Button trigger modal -->
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-bs-toggle="modal" data-bs-target="#staticBackdrop">
      Launch static backdrop modal
    </button>

    <!-- Modal -->
    <div class="modal fade" id="staticBackdrop" data-bs-backdrop="static" data-bs-keyboard="false" tabindex="-1" aria-labelledby="staticBackdropLabel" aria-hidden="true">
      <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
          <div class="modal-header">
            <h1 class="modal-title fs-5" id="staticBackdropLabel">Modal title</h1>
            <button type="button" class="btn-close" data-bs-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"></button>
          </div>
          <div class="modal-body">
            ...
          </div>
          <div class="modal-footer">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-bs-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Understood</button>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

I basically copied the code from the Bootstrap Website, so i can't really figure out why this is not working. I am working in Pycharm with Python and Flask Framework. Also I've read somewhere that I should use an appropriate Popper for Bootstrap 5, how can I do that?

EDIT:
I've now tried to add the popper with these two lines of code, but it doesn't work stil..

```
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@popperjs/core@2.9.2/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-IQsoLXl5PILFhosVNubq5LC7Qb9DXgDA9i+tQ8Zj3iwWAwPtgFTxbJ8NT4GN1R8p" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/@popperjs/core@2/dist/umd/popper.js">
```

Comment: Here's some helpful information on popovers in bootstrap, you are indeed missing popper.js https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.1/components/popovers/

Comment: there is not contact us button your html, is this normal ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your example did not include the bootstrap JS file.  I have included that and it works just fine.  Note that you can include `bootstrap.bundle.min.js` which is the same as including both `bootstrap.min.js` and `popper.min.js` but it's combined into a single file

I recommend reading the introduction part of the docs which goes over these basics: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.3/getting-started/introduction/

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-rbsA2VBKQhggwzxH7pPCaAqO46MgnOM80zW1RWuH61DGLwZJEdK2Kadq2F9CUG65" crossorigin="anonymous">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/6.4.2/css/all.min.css" integrity="sha512-z3gLpd7yknf1YoNbCzqRKc4qyor8gaKU1qmn+CShxbuBusANI9QpRohGBreCFkKxLhei6S9CQXFEbbKuqLg0DA==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"/>

<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.2/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-C6RzsynM9kWDrMNeT87bh95OGNyZPhcTNXj1NW7RuBCsyN/o0jlpcV8Qyq46cDfL" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<div class="container border">

  <!-- Button trigger modal -->
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-bs-toggle="modal" data-bs-target="#staticBackdrop">
    Launch static backdrop modal
  </button>

  <!-- Modal -->
  <div class="modal fade" id="staticBackdrop" data-bs-backdrop="static" data-bs-keyboard="false" tabindex="-1" aria-labelledby="staticBackdropLabel" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
      <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
          <h1 class="modal-title fs-5" id="staticBackdropLabel">Modal title</h1>
          <button type="button" class="btn-close" data-bs-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"></button>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
          ...
        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-bs-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Understood</button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

</div>
```

Comment: Oh I see, this comes in the <body> section.. Thank you very much!

Comment: @codian40V3You mean the `<script>` tag I added?  It can be in the `<head>` if needed. You just have to include it somewhere for that part of Bootstrap to work. You original example didn't have it anywhere.

Comment: Ok weird. If im not mistaking it for another script, i've tried it in the `<head>` but it didn't work.. Thank you eitherways!

Comment: It just depends on the loading order.  Stuff in the `<head>` loads before the content does.  If you put the script at the end of the `<body>` then it will load after all of the HTML content, which is probably what you want most of the time anyway, and if you look at [the bootstrap documentation](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.3/getting-started/introduction/) that is what they recommend too.